# Reference Fields in Custom Metadata records in Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, custom-metadata

I'm making a visualforce page that basically has 4 big buttons that each link to a different dashboard. Each button has a name, some description, and a link.

I thought I would try to store this info in a custom metadata object, one record for each of the buttons. Then in the VF page I would reference each value as appropriate. Then when someone needed to update the description they could do so without editing the VF page directly.

But I'm struggling to access the values from the custom metadata records. I tried the below code, but that's only giving me an Unknown property error.

`{!$ObjectType.CustomMetadataType__mdt.RecordName.FieldName__c}`

How do I reference specific Custom Metadata Record Fields? Or is there some other way I should be doing this all together?

Comment: I don't think this is possible without using an apex VF controller - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.custommetadatatypes_accessing.htm&type=5

Comment: As cropredy said above, you need to create an apex controller class for your visualforce page to query your custom metadata records. Don't think there is any way around that.